# How to get the HTML TD sibling following (the TD whose child table has a TD whose span i got)?

Tags: html, dom, xpath

I have a td (`id=opdBrowser:todaysPatientsTable:5:j_id556`) which has a table(`class=panelGrid`) which has the condition i want. Now i need to get out of the table and go to the anchor `id="opdBrowser:todaysPatientsTable:5:createQueueNoLinkId"` which is in the peer td `id="opdBrowser:todaysPatientsTable:5:j_id675"`.

what is the XPath when i am in the span of the td of the table, and need to go out of the table and get the next td ?

The relevant HTML is here :

```
<td id="opdBrowser:todaysPatientsTable:5:j_id556" class="rich-table-cell alignAndWrap ">
<table class="panelGrid" width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
</td>
<td id="opdBrowser:todaysPatientsTable:5:j_id675" class="rich-table-cell alignAndWrap ">
<a id="opdBrowser:todaysPatientsTable:5:createQueueNoLinkId" title="Create Encounter">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to go up a level, you can use `..`, for example:

```
//table[@class="panelGrid"]/../../td[a/@title="Create Encounter"]
```

would select the `td` containing a link titled "Create Encounter", in the same `table` as your first selected `table`.

If you really want the following sibling, and not select the sibling you want with some condition, you can also do

```
//td[table/@class="panelGrid"]/following-sibling::td
```

Does it answer your question?